# Why does Firefox insert a space after special characters when using a font-face?

Tags: firefox, fonts, operating-systems

When browsing a website that uses accented characters (or special characters) and a css `font-family` feature, Firefox inserts a white space (not a real space character) after the accented character.

It works on Chrome and Safari.

Firefox rendering :[image: Firefox rendering]

Chrome rendering :[image: Chrome rendering]

What can I do to prevent this ?

I'm using Firefox 64 on OS X 10.14.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer [stackoverflow.com/a/50330798/105240](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330798/105240) explains it for me.

> The problem is likely that you are using the 'COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT' (U+0301) along with the U character instead of the 'LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE' (U+00FA) Ú.
>
> The former character set is not in your font so the browser has to use an other system font

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with Firefox, but with your font or with the website.

If this is only on one website, then let us know which one.

Otherwise, use an extension like
[Font Finder (revived)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-inspect/)
to find out which is the problematic font.

Once you find which font, you may decide to delete it from your computer,
or download a better version of it and install.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330798/105240 explains it for me. What I don't understand is why it works in Chrome ?

Comment: Each browser has its own algorithm for choosing fonts.